# Finding key value with the highest value

Tags: python

I have been trying to find the key of the highest value within a nested dictionary. I already have a "working" solution, but I'd like to know how to make it better.

Given a nested dictionary such as:

```
data={
  item_name_1: {
    city_name1 : {price : 100, date: 22/10}, 
    city_name2: {price :120, date: 22/10}
  },
  item_name_2: {
    city_name1 : {price : 105, date: 22/10},
    city_name2: {price :125, date: 22/10}
  }
}
```

I'd like to find the highest value for the `item_name`, and the city where this item has the highest value.

I can do it by making a for loop through all `item_names` in my dictionary:

```
for item_name in data:
```

then using a max function to find the highest price:

```
max_value = max(data[item_name][i]["min_price"] for i in data[item_name])
```

and then run through the key and values of the cities, I find the key which matches my value:

```
for k, v in data[item_name].items():
    if data[item_name][k]["min_price"] == max_value:
        print(k)
```

I'd like to know a better way to do this, given that it has many problems like making a loop twice.

If possible, I'd like to know if this is possible using only the `max` function.
I saw some examples and thought about doing something like this:

```
max_value = max([(data[item_name][i]["min_price"],i) for i in data[item_name]], key=lambda x: data[item_name][i]["min_price"]])
```

Trying to return a tuple of the `price` and the `city_name`, but it didn't work
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.items()` and `max()`'s `key=` parameter.

```
item_highest = {}
for item_name, item_data in data.items():
    item_highest[item_name] = max(
        item_data.items(),
        key=lambda pair: pair[1]["price"],
    )
```

`item_highest` will end up mapping item names to tuples `(city_name, {...}`) where `{...}` is the data for the city.

To get the tuples you want in the end, further unpack and repack a bit:

```
item_highest = {}
for item_name, item_data in data.items():
    city_name, city_data = max(
        item_data.items(),
        key=lambda pair: pair[1]["price"],
    )
    item_highest[item_name] = (
        city_name,
        city_data["price"],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way using `dict comprehensions`:

**STEP 1:**

```
Z = {y:max(data[y].items(), key=lambda x:x[1]['price']) for y in data.keys()}
```

(for each key of data, pick the value with highest price in it)
then `Z` will be:

```
{'item_name_1': ('city_name2', {'price': 120, 'date': '22/10'}),
 'item_name_2': ('city_name2', {'price': 125, 'date': '22/10'})}
```

**STEP2:**
Now you can reshape it accordingly:

```
{x:(y[0], y[1]['price']) for (x,y) in Z.items()}
```

**OUTPUT:**
which results in:

```
{'item_name_1': ('city_name2', 120), 'item_name_2': ('city_name2', 125)}
```